# JavaScript Map RangeError: Invalid array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I am using the [docx node library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx) and attempting to autogenerate a table from an array. The challenge is that beyond returning data I need to return a structure, but when I run my map it fails with the following:

> RangeError: Invalid array length

Here is my sample code I am testing with.

```
const rowChildren = [
    {firstName : "Susan", lastName: "Steward"},
    {firstName : "Daniel", lastName: "Longbottom"},
    {firstName : "Jacob", lastName: "Black"}
  ];

const table = new Table({
    rows: [rowChildren.map(function(element){ return new TableRow({
      children: [
        new TableCell({
        children: [new Paragraph(element.firstName)],
    }), //each entry is an array of TableCell that make up this row
],
    })},
),
],
  });
```

Comment: You're creating an array of arrays. Use only `map`, not the array literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map() already return an array `TableRow[]`, just remove you [ ] before map() at `rows` key. This will resolve your **RangeError: Invalid array length** error.